# Dynamic DrawerNavigator without using Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation-drawer

I need to display the drawer after user logged in. Load the drawer after user successfully logged in, not before.

Not logged in (UI page list) :

```
# Register
# Login
# Info
```

After logged in (Drawer UI page list) :

```
# My Account
# Other Function
# Other Function
# Logout
```

How to make this works without using Redux?

Answer (score 0):

You can use stack-navigator and add your before login screens, then add the drawer-navigator inside that stack-navigator. In your drawer-navigator add your after login screens.

```
const MyApp = createStackNavigator({
  Register: {
    screen: Register
  },
  Login: {
    screen: Login
  },
  Info: {
    screen: Info
  },
  Drawer: {
    screen: Drawer
  }
});

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator({
  MyAccount: {
    screen: MyAccount,
  },
  Notifications: {
    screen: MyNotificationsScreen,
  },
});
```